# How to run Ansible playbook to multiple servers in a right way?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Ansible use ssh to setup softwares to remote hosts.

If there are some fresh machines just been installed, run Ansible playbook from one host will not connect them because of no authorized_keys on remote hosts.

If copy the Ansible host's pub key to those target hosts like:

```
$ ssh user@server "echo \"`cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub`\" >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

First should ssh login and make file on every remote host:

```
$ mkdir .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Is this the common way to run Ansible playbook to remote servers? Is there a better way exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to do that using Ansible as well, with the [`authorized_key` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html). For example, to authorize your key for user `root`:

```
ansible <hosts> -m authorized_key -a "user=root state=present key=\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"" --ask-pass
```

This can be done in a playbook also, with the target user as a variable that defaults to `root`:

```
- hosts: <NEW_HOSTS>
  vars:
  - username: root    

  tasks:
  - name: Add authorized key
    authorized_key: 
      user: "{{ username }}"
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/<YOUR_USER>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

And executed with:

```
ansible-playbook auth.yml --ask-pass -e username=<TARGET_USER>
```

Your user should have privileges, if not use `became`.

Comment: This way `--ask-pass` can ask the first host's password. If there are multiple hosts with different passwords, doesn't work.

Comment: That's true. Anyway, I think it's better than manually login and load the public key. You can use multiple times the first command for differents hosts, or better, find out how to create the fresh servers with a predefined login. There are tools to get this, like Packer for VMs or preseeding for bare-metal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a `ansible_ssh_pass` variable to `hosts` file. I set multiple hosts' password there. Then just include the `auth.yml` from root playbook. It's a good solution for me now.