# how can add my private key to a target host through ansible

Tags: vagrant, ansible, devops

i have an shh key from /home/renz/.shh/id_rsa.pub. I want to add this to my target host in /root/.shh/authorized_keys through ansible. I tried this but didn't work.

```
---
- hosts: snapzio
  tasks:
    - name: Set authorized key took from file
      authorized_key:
        user: master
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/renz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
        path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

because in the first place, i cannot communicate with the host because my key is not in the authorized keys. I think this idea makes sense if i want to communicate to many hosts. instead of just manually copy and paste the key.

Comment: If you can't use public key authentication, you have to use password authentication. I don't get what this question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Ansible playbook to multiple servers in a right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276426/how-to-run-ansible-playbook-to-multiple-servers-in-a-right-way)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if the account you use with Ansible doesn't have a SSH key installed, you'll have to fall back to using password authentication.  Assuming InstallMyKey.yml is your playbook, you could run something like this:

```
ansible-playbook InstallMyKey.yml --ask-become-pass
```

You'll need to add the `remote_user: root` line to your YML between the `hosts:` and `tasks:` lines, then type in the root password.

Assuming the playbook succeds and everything else in the root SSH settings are correct, your next run of a playbook should use the `renz` ssh key and get on without a password.